# Average Difference of Averages

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation, mean, weighted-mean, differences

I'm looking at the gender pay gap across the UK using some data from the ONS.

The data is released as mean and median gross pay by sex by local authority area. Figures for England as a whole are also given.

I therefore have a collection of averages. What I'm actually interested in are the differences between those averages (e.g. on average males in Rochester earn £100 more than females).

I also have some weighting information in terms of the number of jobs.

What I'm wondering is how can I say whether an area is significantly different from the England average?

Do I need to derive variance information from the local authority level data and apply this to the England overall values? I presume I need to do some weighting but I'm unsure on how to do this when I'm looking at differences (ie males and females will have a different weighting so which would be applied to the difference?).

Below is an R example of how the data is structured:

```
data.frame(
    "Area_Name"=c("England","England","Wolverhampton","Wolverhampton"),
    "Sex"=c("Male","Female","Male","Female"),
    "Jobs_Thousands"=c(10886,10520,50,46),
    "Mean_Gross_Pay"=c(622.4,404.8,538,347.6),
    "Median_Gross_Pay"=c(523.4,339.8,463.1,293.9)
    )
```

Comment: I would start with some graphical methods, maybe a line plot , some kind of stripchart, each local area a line with averages for male/female indicated, maybe by color.  Can you post the data?